# How do I lose focus of the snap function?

Tags: xbox-one

When I tell my xbox one to snap TV, my screen splits and puts my cable tv on the right.   How do I get control of the left half of my screen again?   I am pretty sure I tried every button, but I cannot get focus of the left side of my screen.

*If a picture is needed, I will post one shortly.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press the Home/Guide button twice, it switches focus between the main screen and the snapped app. You can also say "Xbox Switch" to switch focus.